# How can you use Lazy<> with AutoMock (Moq)

Tags: c#, moq, autofac, mstest, automocking

We are using Autofac.Extras.Moq.AutoMock.
Now I have a constructor dependency using Lazy<>

```
public MyService(Lazy<IDependency> myLazyDependency) {...}
```

to test `MyService` we need to mock the `Lazy<Dependency>`.

I am trying this with

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void Init(TestContext context)
{
    autoMock = AutoMock.GetLoose();
}

[TestInitialize]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
     var myDepMock = autoMock.Mock<Lazy<IDependency>>();  // <-- throws exception
}
```

This is the exception returned by the test runner:

Initialization method Tests.MyServiceTests.MyTestInitialize threw exception. System.InvalidCastException: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Lazy`1[IDependency]' to type 'Moq.IMocked`1[System.Lazy`1[IDependency]]'..

So, how can I pass a Lazy<> mocked object using automock.

Comment: Why not mock `IDependency`, and then pass in `new Lazy(mockedObj)` (or however it's built - I forgot)? There's no reason to mock `Lazy`, you're not testing the system framework.

Comment: Good idea, but I can't get it to work.  You need to pass a lambda.  MockedObj isn't accepted.

Comment: Then pass something like `new Lazy(() => mockedObj)` :)

Comment: Doh.  Forgot the type.  It's Lazy<IDependency>(() => automockedObject).  Thanks a lot.  If you put this in the response, i'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You needn't mock `Lazy`, as it's part of the framework (barring some extreme circumstances). You can simply mock `IDependency` and pass the mocked object to `Lazy`.

Something like this should work:

```
var mockDependency = autoMock.Mock<IDependency>();
var mockObject = mockDependency.Object; //(Not entirely sure of the property for this library)
var mockedLazy = new Lazy<IDependency>(() => mockObject);
```

Note that this will mean `Lazy` essentially will do nothing for your tests (if that's an issue) - it'll simply return the already created mock when it's first used

Comment: For those interested I got a similar response from the automock guys: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extras.Moq/issues/3